# jQuery each - Esclarecimento

Tags: jquery, setinterval

Preciso que a cada x segundos uma `li` do meu menu seja escondida e tenho esse código:

```
$('.area-menu .close').click(function(){
    delayed();
});

function delayed() {
    var liMenu = $('.area-menu li').not('.marginless');
    var time = 1000;

    liMenu.each(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($(this));
        }, time);
        time += 1000;
    });
}
```

Porém quando eu logo o `$(this)` ele não me retorna nada. Como faria pra dar um `hide()` que seja em cada `li` do meu menu? E onde eu estou errando?

Comment: Já descobri o que é. E meio que entendi o porque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens um problema duplo de contexto. Dentro de `setTimeout` o contexto não é o mesmo da função onde ele foi corrido. O `this` refere-se a `window` (contexto global) e não ao elemento iterado pelo jQuery. Dentro de um loop podes usar os argumentos passados à callback (index e elemento), ou podes criar uma referência ao this com `var el = this;` por exemplo, fora de setTimeout, mas dentro do loop.

Solução:

```
function delayed() {
    var liMenu = $('.area-menu li').not('.marginless');
    var time = 1000;

    liMenu.each(function(i, el) {
        // ou var el = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($(el));
        }, time);
        time += 1000; // ou somente  "}, time * (i + 1));"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

geralmente o que se faz é instanciar o this fora do método de callback.
ex:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    //aqui use a variável self para acessar o objeto que chamou o callback
    //no caso se fosse window mesmo não faz muita diferença já que você pode utilizar o objeto window
}, time);
```